# Should I worry about cleaning up large objects in Node.js or leave it for the garbage collector?

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection, v8

Recently I ran into an issue with a node.js API where my memory was growing larger and larger with every request. I'm hosting my server on Heroku using their free version which is only 512MB of RAM. After getting a lot of traffic over the weekend, I started getting exceeded memory errors from Heroku so I began searching for a memory leak in my code to no avail. I wasn't keeping around any objects, everything should have been getting cleaned up and quite frankly, I was lost.

However, after doing some research, I found node.js runs the garbage collector when the max-old-space-size variable is reached and is defaulted to 1024MB on 64-bit systems. I've set this to 410 (80% of my available memmory) but wonder if I should just handle this in the code? Obviously it would be ideal to upgrade my instance and just have the normal default cap but that's not an option right now.

Example:

```
// lets assume there is some apiGet function
// that calls back with a very very large object with
// the following structure:
// {
//      status: "success",
//      statusCode: 200,
//      messages: [],
//      data: { users: [ huge array of users ] }
// }
// we have a manipulateData function that's going
// to do some stuff to the returned data and the
// call some callback to give the data to the caller
function manipulateData(callback) {
    apiGet(function(error, veryLargeObject) {
        var users = veryLargeObject.data.users;
        var usefulUsers = users.map(function(user) {
            // do some data calculations here and then
            // return just those properties we needed
        });

        callback(null, usefulUsers)
    });
}
```

So in this example, once manipulateData is done running, if I understand correctly, the "veyLargeObject" is now going to be set for garbage collection since there aren't any more pointers that have access to it (the returned usefulUsers is a new array created by the map). But this doesn't necessarily mean that all the memory that it was taking up is free, correct? Would it be wise to set veryLargeObject = null or undefined before calling the callback?

I hope what I'm asking makes sense. Basically: Is it a good idea to set large objects to null or undefined when there's no intent to use them anymore or should they just be left around for the garbage collector to clean up? Does the answer to this question change when you're only given 512MB of RAM vs having 8GB of RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're certain that a given object is no longer needed, then setting it to null is the way to go (be aware that this does not imply that any linked objects will also be garbage-collected to). Only when all references to that given object are set to null (the object becomes inaccessible from anywhere on your code), then it will be collected.

Since node.js uses the V8 engine under the hood, you can get some hints on how to improve garbage collection [A tour of V8: Garbage Collection](http://jayconrod.com/posts/55/a-tour-of-v8-garbage-collection). If that's not enough, you can force GC by following [these instructions](https://simonmcmanus.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/forcing-garbage-collection-with-node-js-and-v8/).

Comment: In this particular instance, it is already going out of scope with nothing to keep it alive, how would setting it to `null` help? There may be cases where it applies, but not here.

Comment: It will go out of scope if it isn't stored anywhere else outside this scope during the execution of "callback" (a higher-level function, even a global variable), so that there are active references still after manipulateData finished its execution. Since I don't have more code to analyze, I'm inclined to providing more generic information.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Lets assume that it isn't used anywhere else after callback is called..i realize that this is now out of scope but isn't the object still taking up memory after it's been marked for garbage collection?

Comment: Until GC is run, the object is still taking up heap space. That's why I suggested using V8's forced garbage collection (https://simonmcmanus.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/forcing-garbage-collection-with-node-js-and-v8/). It MIGHT help you in this situation, since you know there's no other reference to the object and GC can be beneficial.

Comment: I've used the --expose-gc to test everything. It's how I found out about my issue but isn't it a bad idea to do that in production environment?

Comment: V8/node.js now uses "incremental GC" (instead of the previous "stop-the-world" mode) which make long GC-related pauses a thing of the past. So, under normal conditions, GC should not take longer than 50ms (it might be a bit longer if your object is really large). If you don't abuse it, it should not cripple runtime performance but you should test it to see how it works on your specific workload. Also, it would be a good idea to attempt to make the "veryLargeObject" as small as possible or, even better, only request/transfer the pieces of that object you really need.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a variable to `null` is only necessary in certain kind of closure situations, e.g. :

```
function createClosure(bigData) {
    var unrelatedVar = 1;

    doSomethingAsync(function theCallback(err, result) {
        if (bigData.matches(result)) {
            ...
        }
    });

    return function theReturnedFunction() {
        return unrelatedVar++;
    };
}
```

In V8 same-level closures share the same context object where closed over variables are located. All the same-level closures then point to the context object, so it will stay alive until all the functions are dead. So here `theReturnedFunction` and `theCallback` are both same-level functions that both point to the same context object with 2 members: bigData and unrelatedVar. So as long
as the returned function is alive, the bigData is alive as well even though it cannot be referenced.

This is really easy to fall into because closed over vars look exactly like local variables, while in fact they act like an object's fields (which would use explicit `this.field` so it's always obvious). This is not any different from having to set an explicit object's `.bigData` field to null after it's unused, but when it's an explicit object it's much harder to miss.